# How does TcpClient improve on raw Sockets?

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, tcpclient

I have seen in a couple of places people saying `TcpClient` and `NetworkStream` are preferred to raw `Socket` use, for instance that they help in terms of "Data Framing" whereby messages received from the server can be in any number of pieces that need parsing and piecing together into the original messages (calls to Send / Receive are not guaranteed 1:1)

What I don't understand is *how* it is better in this regard? It surely cannot magically piece messages back together since that information isn't transmitted over TCP. It can't expect additional data to be sent about message length otherwise it wouldn't be compatible with most TCP servers, only those using TcpListener.

Reading data from a `NetworkStream` seems pretty similar to receiving data from a `Socket` so could someone explain how it makes my life easier as a novice TCP coder?

Comment: `It surely cannot magically piece messages back together since that information isn't transmitted over TCP` you sure about that?

Comment: Yes. TCP is a stream of bytes, not datagrams like UDP. Sending N bytes in a single `send()` call doesn't cause the same exact buffer to be returned in a single `recv()` call on the other end. It *might*, but it's not guaranteed. Devices might break it into smaller chunks or lump it together with the previous or next chunk. It can be affected by MTA settings as it's routed through various networks. Boundary markers are not part of the TCP protocol, so the application has to determine where those boundaries are based on the content. `TcpClient` has no concept of the application protocol.

Comment: So then, how does it help? I can see `NetworkStream.DataAvailable` Property but what else?

Comment: My best guess is that 1) it separates the concept of the socket (and its state) from its stream of data, 2) it provides a client-focused API (`Socket` neither knows nor cares which end it is), and 3) its Async API is compatible with `async`/`await` whereas `Socket` still uses `IAsyncResult` with `Begin`/`End` methods.

Answer (score 2):

This is possibly a bit like asking why use `System.Net.Sockets` (which provides an API to `WinSock` rather than writing our own `WinSock` API.

`TcpClient` abstracts away the many different ways to establish a Socket and makes only a few very common ones available.  Additionally it makes handling things like buffers easier.  Likewise `NetworkStream` abstracts away the many different ways to read/write from a socket and allows you to use more familar streams on top of `NetworkStream`.  Such as `TextWriter` and `TextReader`.

They don't really make any difference in terms of Data Framing.  You still need to know where the data you're looking for starts and ends.  Although if your data framing is a good old line of text, then TextReader and TextWriter on top of NetworkStream make that quite bliss.

IMO, the biggest single advantage for both TcpClient and NetworkStream is the Async methods and the incredibly simple means to develop non blocking IO client/server code.  While you can do this with straight Sockets, it's a lot harder and more complex.

If you're starting out, I would recommend skipping NetworkStream altogether (for reading) and using `System.IO.Pipelines` - which sits on top of a `NetworkStream`, this further abstracts the NetworkStream away and makes development faster still.

Sure you can do everything that `TcpClient` and `NetworkStream` provide yourself by interacting directly with the Socket, but you'll find yourself writing a lot of duplicate code with a lot of edge cases that have already been thought out in `TcpClient` and `NetworkStream`.